# WalletConnect React Native - No events fired

Tags: react-native, mobile, wallet, wallet-connect

I'm having a hard time getting WalletConnect 1.7.7 to work on React Native. I want to integrate in a crypto `Wallet` to handle dapps requests. Their documentation is...lacking. I'm following the "[quickstart](https://docs.walletconnect.com/quick-start/wallets/react-native)" in their docs, but listeners never gets fired.

```
import WalletConnect from "@walletconnect/client";

// Create connector
const connector = new WalletConnect(
  {
    // Required
    uri: "wc:8a5e5bdc-a0e4-47...TJRNmhWJmoxdFo6UDk2WlhaOyQ5N0U=",
    // Required
    clientMeta: {
      description: "WalletConnect Developer App",
      url: "https://walletconnect.org",
      icons: ["https://walletconnect.org/walletconnect-logo.png"],
      name: "WalletConnect",
    },
  });

connector.on("session_request", (error, payload) => {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  }

  // Handle Session Request
});
```

But `session_request` or any other event never get's fired. As per their documents that's all I need. Is there anything else I'm missing or perhaps it's not documented?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for Wallet Connect is very incomplete and there is very little information on the web. Are you using React Native with Expo? Because there the implementation changes. I don't see any flaws in your code. Test your integration from this website https://example.walletconnect.org/.

Answer (score 0):

Using **connect** event instead of **session_request** on walllet connect works for me in react native.

```
 connector.on('connect',(error,payload)=>{
        console.log('eventtt',payload)
      // Alert.alert('Connected')
     })
```